# Fresh install of nginx causes browser to download index.html instead of opening it

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

When I view this in Chrome, `http://localhost:90` the file is downloaded instead of displayed in Chrome.

This question has been asked a lot of times on SO, but about index.**php** files.  My problem is a plain jane **HTML** file, not a PHP file.  That hasn't been asked yet.  I was hoping the solution would be similar, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Here's my example.com.conf:

```
server
{
    server_name localhost;
    listen 90;
    root /var/www/example.com/html
    index index.html

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

My index.html file contains only two words, no markup

```
Hello World
```

I think it's the mime.types.  The mime.types file has the entry for html in it.  This is a fresh nginx install.

`nginx -t` reports "test is successful"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that mime.types has the extension "html" with the text/html file. This [post](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/194023) details how to force nginx to serve an html for download instead of display, so perhaps the reverse works.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

I think that is the problem, you need put your location / first and then you can also add it before ( bad english, I try improve )

Or try whit this vHost:

```
server {
    listen   90;
    server_name  localhost;
autoindex on;
    location / {
        root   /var/www/example.com/html;
        index  index.html;
}
}
```